# How can the UK government have spent £37 billion (US $51 billion) on the "Test & Trace System"?

Tags: united-kingdom, covid-19

Whether £37 billion be the amount that has been spent, or simply the Test & Trace budget for the first two years as [this site](https://fullfact.org/online/37bn-test-trace-spending/) suggests, I find it inconceivable that such amounts are remotely relevant.

When you consider that the UK's entire defence budget only amounts to £42 billion (US $58 billion), how could you actually spend money of that order on testing & tracing?

Comment: It should be pointed out that it hasn't yet spent £37 billion. £22bn has already been spent and £15bn more has been allocated to it in this year's budget. Yes, it seems high and there have been questions asked, but until a full cost breakdown is released (and probably a public enquiry) we're unlikely to get an answer to your question that is any more than speculation.

Comment: It's also not a great point of comparison to take a small standing armed force and compare it to the start-up cost of a new initiative. The old saw of good/fast/cheap does have some truth to it (not that I'm saying test & trace has proved to be any of those things).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what this question is asking for - is it just a breakdown of the spending that you're after? That would seem to be answered by the Full Fact article you linked to, along with the [report from the National Audit Office](https://www.nao.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/The-governments-approach-to-test-and-trace-in-England-interim-report.pdf) it refers to.

Comment: @CDJB It is just that the number seems out of all touch with reality. If I asked you to go out and spend £37 billion over the next twelve months - on anything - it is not something you would find easy to do.

Comment: @origimbo The "small standing armed force" includes a nuclear submarine fleet, number of nuclear-powered hunter-killer subs, two aircraft carriers, all the RAF aircraft and bases, the army and countless bases, and the TA. I'm finding it hard to compare in terms of cost the testing of people in existing car parks, with some temporary tents and structures put up, and volunteers to man telephones. My own belief is that the government are allocating to Covid, stuff which has nothing to do with Covid.  For the rest of this government's life - all bad economic news will be blamed on Covid.

Comment: @WS2 I would hire 370000 people for £100000/year each (including overhead)

Comment: @user253751 Good answer. I think it proves my point.

Comment: @user253751 You appear to lack an understanding of how difficult it is to quickly hire large numbers of (with that kind of salary probably well-qualified) people (and organize their employment).

Comment: I'm guessing by "remotely relevant" you mean "remotely real[istic]" or something like that. Note that it includes testing as well, which could involve plenty of infrastructure, research grants etc. Also from the link you gave "Actual spending on Test and Trace was £5.7bn up to the end of November 2020, and is expected to be close to  £20bn by the beginning of April."

Comment: Also, just a hunch: since the emergence of the famous Kent strain (B 1.1.7) the UK has spent loads of money on sequencing, which is much more expensive than usual testing. https://www.wsj.com/articles/how-the-u-k-became-world-leader-in-sequencing-the-coronavirusgenome-11612011601 That might explain in part why the figure is estimated to have tripled for the past 6 months (compared to the previous 6), but it could well be for other reasons.

Comment: @Fizz I have no doubt that every remotely connected cost imaginable has been included - perhaps the complete redecoration of the offices of the Health Secretary and all his officials.

Comment: @Roland Well the 100000 includes the cost of hiring them.

Comment: @Fizz sadly it doesn't seem to have had much effect, with Britain having the highest per-capita death toll of any large country.

Comment: It also includes any economic rent paid to the owners of PCR machines, probably, too.

Comment: It should be pointed out that this price would be the equivalent of over £550 for *every person in the UK* which would have been enough to individually test everyone, at home. We already have a nationwide infrastructure under govt. control for such things, it's called the NHS.

Comment: The UK spending figures do look a bit silly though. Germany plans to spend 200m euros on sequencing. https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-germany-sequencing-idUSKBN29J1KS I'm not sure what their whole test & trace budget is. I'd suggest that to make this a more serious question you could e.g. ask how that UK T&T budget compares with other large European countries. (Also, I suggest you edit in an actual quote from the article you linked, instead of asking about the 37B figure they are debunking.)

Comment: Even The Times which has been mostly supportive of Johnson's government quoted the total allocated to T&T at £37 billion. So I don't think the figure itself (with the quantifiers that it is budgeted and over two years) is in anyway questioned. https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/37bn-test-and-trace-system-had-little-impact-on-covid-rates-hrwrftwr6

Comment: @GeoffAtkins: I guess that could make it a question on Skeptics then, but the debunking is obvious and is in the link the OP gave.

Comment: As I said in my first comment, until a full costing has been issued by the government or we get a public inquiry into this affair, it's unlikely there could be an answer as to *how* £37bn was spent on T&T that wasn't speculation. It's certainly fair to say that the govt's procurement procedures during Covid have been lax, but £37bn is certainly an outrageous sum.

Comment: @Fizz Some people for reasons best understood by them have chosen to close the question. Anyway I think I've managed to get the subject a fairly good airing. So let's leave it there.

Comment: Here's a [bit of amusement to read up on](https://www.theregister.com/2021/03/10/pac_test_and_trace/).  More on that site re. same subject - they *really* dislike Dido Harding.  That $1000000/yr quip?  Perhaps not as far off as one might hope, average consultant rate was £1100/day.

Answer (score 3):

> **[1] How can the UK government have spent £37 billion (US $51 billion) on the “Test & Trace System”?**

**It hasn't.**

It has spent £4 billion up to October 2020. £5.7 billion by the end of November 2020.

From [Public Accounts Committee --
Oral evidence: COVID-19: Test, track and trace
(part 1), HC 932 --
Monday 18 January 2021](https://committees.parliament.uk/oralevidence/1524/default/#page=36)

> **Q107 James Wild:** I have a few questions about the budget. The budget
> through to the end of this financial year is £22 billion. At the time of the
> Report, £4 billion had been spent. Mr Williams has talked about a further
> £1.3 billion of contracts that have been signed. How much of that £22
> billion do you expect to spend by the end of the financial year? That is to
> either Mr Williams or Baroness Harding.

> **David Williams:** Let me pick that up. In terms of the spend year to date,
> I can update it by another month. We have data until the end of
> November, and we have now spent £5.7 billion. The forecast is
> backloaded. The central assessment of the team is that they will spend
> more than £20 billion of that £22 billion, but we continue to develop new
> use cases, particularly for community testing, the use of lateral flow
> devices, and so on. Some of that currently identified forecast underspend

---

> **[2] Whether £37 billion be the amount that has been spent, or simply the Test & Trace budget for the first two years**

It is the budget for two years.

---

> **[3] how could you actually spend money of that order on testing & tracing?**

Some of the money will have been spent funding laboratories that process up to 960,000 tests a day, raising capacity from the initial 3000 tests a day. Around 100,000,000 tests have been made.

Some of that money will have been spent employing, training, organising and equipping up to 20,000 contact tracing staff. Over 3 million people with positive test results were contacted and over 6 million of their contacts have been contacted. In many cases this will have been straightforward but it can be non-trivial as illustrated by the extreme efforts needed to track down the person who submitted a test that was positive for the Brazilian variant and who didn't fill in their details.

Whether those amounts are necessary or worthwhile or whether much has been wasted are separate questions that this answer does not attempt to address. No doubt the Public Accounts Committee and others will.

- https://www.independent.co.uk/news/health/coronavirus-nhs-test-and-trace-jobs-b1814601.html
- https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/details/testing
- https://www.statista.com/statistics/1028731/covid19-tests-select-countries-worldwide/
- https://www.bmj.com/content/372/bmj.n592

Comment: From the fullfact article: "£4 billion was spent up to the end of October. We don’t yet know how much the whole first year will cost." So that figure is not accurate. Nor does it address why £22bn was budgeted for this system in the first year.

Comment: @Fizz: good point. I'll update answer and try to find better data - but the *"have spent £37 billion"* certainly remains wrong.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins: That isn't the question posted. The question posted asks how can the UK government have spent £37 billion. That's past tense.

Comment: Then surely you should address why the question mentions £37bn? And the reason that number is used is because that's how much money is budgeted to the UK's T&T system over two years. If you seek to answer the question, you should explain why that money was budgeted and why the system currently in place didn't cost as much.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins: to be fair, the OP phrased this as if the gov't has already spent that 37B sum; so this is a good enough answer to that (now).

Comment: @Fizz, that's fair enough, but if the question was wrong, the answer should explain why it was wrong, not just dismiss it when it was close.

Comment: I do feel that the edits make this a much better answer.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins The title of a question is not the question. The past tense is not used in the question text itself. And in fact, the headline on the article it links to contains "has not spent". The question is clearly about the amount, not the specific time frame.